# How do I select multiple reg keys?

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

When I try to select multiple keys in `RegEdit`, it just selects one at a time.

How can I select multiple keys?

Comment: exactly like how you select multiple objects in Explorer or most other apps: Shift to select a range and Ctrl a single item

Comment: The only way I'm aware of that allows selecting registry Keys in GUI form is via the [`RegEditX`](https://www.dcsoft.com/products/regeditx/) Crawler search feature and is worth the $10 for a license as there's no other program like it and it's one of the most helpful Registry tools I've ever come across

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I select multiple keys?

You cannot select multiple keys (folders) in either `regedit` or `regedt32` (the Windows built in registry editors).

However there are freeware programs that can be downloaded to do this. Here is one:

[O&O RegEditor](https://www.oo-software.com/en/ooregeditor):

> No installation is needed and all settings are saved in the Profile data, so that O&O RegEditor can easily be used on other computers. Special versions in 32 and 64-Bit are available, meaning certain registry entries can be edited on 64-Bit systems that are normally hidden from 32-Bit users.
>
> Features overview
>
> - Convenient search function
> - **Copy and paste of entire keys, subkeys and their values**
> - Simplified editing
> - Create, manage, import and export favorites
> - Frequently used keys can be preset as favorites
> - REG files optimized for import and export
> - Export the Registry in XML format

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Screenshot:

[image]